# How to use material3 design in andorid studio (xml & java)?

Tags: android-studio, material-design, material-components-android

Does anybody have a guide? and I saw their github for getting started, wasnt very helpfull

**I've added the implementation and I've changed the theme to "Theme.Material3.Light.NoActionBar".**
But im still getting errors of "No documentation found."

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the error?